# Specific child already has a parent

Tags: android, layout, view, fragment, scrollview

I want to create a dynamic layout but I had error

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I found something on Stackoverlow but most of all suggest to use this line that I already use:

> View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false);

Any solution??

ItemFragment.java

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items, container, false);
    layout = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.itmes_fragment_layout);      

    item_folder_button = new Button(getActivity());
    item_folder_button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.items_button_layout);
return rootView;
}

private void createItemsButtons() {       

    layout.removeAllViews();

    if (itemscontainer.length == 0) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(myContext);
        TextView no_items = new TextView(myContext);
        no_items.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_items));
        no_items.setTextSize(35);
        row.addView(no_items);
        layout.addView(row);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= itemscontainer.length; ) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity());
            TableRow.LayoutParams param = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(param);
            tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            for (int y = 0; (y < 3) && (i <= itemscontainer.length); y++) {
                item_folder_button.setText(("Text " + i));                    
                item_folder_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                item_folder_button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                TableRow.LayoutParams par = new TableRow.LayoutParams(y);
                item_folder_button.setLayoutParams(par);
                int id = i;
                item_folder_button.setId(id);
                item_folder_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int btn_selected = item_folder_button.getId();
                        Fragment fragment = new ItemFragment();
                        if (fragment != null) {
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        }
                    }
                });
                tableRow.addView(item_folder_button);
                i++;
            }
            layout.removeView(layout.getRootView());
            layout.addView(tableRow);
        }
    }
}
    return rootView;
}
```

fragment_items.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/items_fragment_scrollview_layout"
>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/items_fragment_linearlayout"
    >
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/items_fragment_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/items_button_layout"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/folder"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:background="@drawable/item_button"
        android:drawablePadding="-75dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to instantiate a new `item_folder_button` each time through the `for` loop.

Comment: `private void createItemsButtons() { ` is inside the `onCreateView()` method. Could you post the right code ?

Comment: I edited it.
I try to create a button each time but its layout doesn't work. item_folder_button.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.items_button_layout);
                   AND item_folder_button = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button_items_layout, null, false);  doesn't work.

Comment: That's not what I mean. `item_folder_button = new Button(getActivity());`. You're doing everything dynamically. Forget about inflating anything. You can get rid of the last two lines of your `onCreateView()` method, too.

Comment: it's the first thing that I tried and worked but buttons didn't have the layout that I want. If I create in this way dinamically buttons how can I use its layout?

Comment: Wait, why didn't `item_folder_button = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button_items_layout, null, false);` work?

Comment: didn't work ... getLayoutInflater() needs parameter

Comment: Right, right. You can use `LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())` instead.

Comment: so, sorry for dummy, what is complete code? :-)

Comment: If `button_items_layout` is _just_ a `Button`, then `item_folder_button = (Button) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.button_items_layout, null, false);`. Of course, it would be better to save a reference to the `LayoutInflater` outside the loop, and use that instead.

Comment: it works! thank you for your patience my dear! :-)